# Can I upload a provisioning profile to iOS Dev Center?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have a provisioning profile on my machine that I have since deleted from iOS dev center. I can't figure out a way to upload it back to the dev center to see it listed under my provisioning profiles. I tried dragging and dropping it, but nothing happened. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't upload a provisioning profile. Just create a new one in the portal, delete the old one, and start using the new one.